# Cannot display alert dialog when i go back and again clicked in android

Tags: android, dialog

`mcqlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Toast.makeText(McqActivity.this, "Selected" + position,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if(position<=list.size()){
                System.out.println("mcq position"+position);
            MCQ item = (MCQ)adapter.getItem(position-1);
            System.out.println("item"+(position-1));
            Intent i = new Intent(McqActivity.this,McqlistonitemclickactionActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            listPosition = position-1;
             id_value=item.getObjectId();
                System.out.println("idval"+id_value);
            question=item.getQuestion();
            System.out.println("question"+question);
            option1=item.getOption1();
            System.out.println("option1"+option1);
            option2=item.getOption2();
            System.out.println("option2"+option2);
            option3=item.getOption3();
            System.out.println("option3"+option3);
            option4=item.getOption4();
            System.out.println("option4"+option4);
            notes=item.getNotes();
            System.out.println("notes"+notes);
            image=item.getImage();
            System.out.println("image"+image);
            answer=item.getAnswer();
            System.out.println("answer"+answer);
            answered=item.getAnswered();
            //i.putExtra("id",item.getId());
            replaceContentView("activity_mcq",i);

                    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_mcq);

            }
        }
    });
```

`
On clicking listview.

This is my code to get alert dialog...This works fine only once i go back to listview and agaiin clicked it cannot get alert dialog dont know where i missed it..Kindly help me out.

notesbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub




        dialog = new Dialog(getParent());

            //dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            //dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            //dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_popupwindow1);
            //dialog.setContentView(view);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.activity_popupwindow1,
                            null, false);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.setContentView(view);
            dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(
                    new ColorDrawable(0));
            //dialog.getCurrentFocus();

                qPosition =McqActivity.listPosition;
                System.out.println("qqhhhhh"+qPosition);


            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(
                    metrics);
            int height = metrics.heightPixels;
            int width = metrics.widthPixels;

            dialog.getWindow().setLayout((int) (width / 1.1),
                    (int) (height / 1.3));
            System.out.println("vvvvv"+height);
            System.out.println("vvvvv"+width);

            Button btnclose = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.popupclosebtn);
            Button btnupdate = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.popupupdatebtn);

            btnclose.setTypeface(lighttypeface);
            btnupdate.setTypeface(lighttypeface);

            ImageView imageshow = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.popupblueview);
            imageshow.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            System.out.println("imagebitmap"+bitmap);
            popupfirsttext = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.popupfirsttext);
            popupfirsttext.setText(McqActivity.question);
            popupnotes = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.popupnotes);
            popupnotes.setText(McqActivity.notes);
            System.out.println("vivek"+note);
            System.out.println("popupnotes : "+popupfirsttext.getText().toString());


            // Display the dialog




            btnupdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Intent i = new Intent(
                            McqlistonitemclickactionActivity.this,
                            PendingtestActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            });
            btnclose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });
            try {
                System.out.println("faulllllll");
                 dialog.show();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
```

This my error i am getting.I have googled it but unable to get exact solution:

03-24 13:33:26.042: W/System.err(14697): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@41c87d88 is not valid; is your activity running?
03-24 13:33:26.051: W/System.err(14697):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:646)
03-24 13:33:26.051: W/System.err(14697):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:248)
03-24 13:33:26.051: W/System.err(14697):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
03-24 13:33:26.051: W/System.err(14697):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
03-24 13:33:26.051: W/System.err(14697):    at com.example.pgmed.McqlistonitemclickactionActivity$6.onClick(McqlistonitemclickactionActivity.java:527)
03-24 13:33:26.051: W/System.err(14697):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4212)
03-24 13:33:26.051: W/System.err(14697):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17476)
03-24 13:33:26.052: W/System.err(14697):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
03-24 13:33:26.052: W/System.err(14697):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
03-24 13:33:26.052: W/System.err(14697):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
03-24 13:33:26.052: W/System.err(14697):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
03-24 13:33:26.052: W/System.err(14697):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-24 13:33:26.053: W/System.err(14697):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-24 13:33:26.053: W/System.err(14697):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
03-24 13:33:26.053: W/System.err(14697):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-24 13:33:26.053: W/System.err(14697):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thanks

Comment: Once i go back to previous activity and agin click it it is not working..

Comment: list View. static  ah.. or dynamic values......

Comment: Hi jack,on clicking listview a button appears on clicking that dialog will show..This works fine only once.whn i again click on second list and click on button dialog is not shown .

Comment: when ever open the listview screen activity before using arraylist.clear(); because when go to another  screen.press back button to arraylist position is changed i think that problem for your code

Comment: I have checked with that before still i am getting this error

Comment: click  list view ->dialog show  right....

Comment: i will post my entire coode here

Comment: 1st position click dialog show. second position click dialog did t show ah..?

Comment: ya i am getting getting the value of second list in sysout...Unable to show the dialog..

Comment: getting listview position on clicking listview then it moves to next activity there on clicking button it should display an dialog.This is what i want.But this happens only once on clicking first list

Comment: This is my listview on click event:

Comment: notesbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { notesbtn is button or listview ...?

Comment: it is a button..it will appear on clicking listview

Comment: i have added a code on my question stats kindly view it.

Comment: do you get my question jack????

Comment: ya i get anand put dialog code all in listview click lisaner your problem is solve

Comment: listview click listener is in another  activity jack..Dialog is in another activity.How can i put it?

Comment: Because i am using some function in dialog activity so i have used like that

Comment: listview click (Intent process) go next actvity then button click -> dialog show  k

Comment: ya...i have used the same one u can see it my code displayed above

Answer (score 0):

```
mcqlistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Toast.makeText(McqActivity.this, "Selected" + position,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if(position<=list.size()){
            System.out.println("mcq position"+position);
        MCQ item = (MCQ)adapter.getItem(position);
        System.out.println("item"+(position));
        Intent i = new Intent(McqActivity.this,McqlistonitemclickactionActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        listPosition = position;//Change this then run
```

Comment: I have used this to get listposition if i remove it i cannot get my position on clicking listview.First it was like  listPosition = position; only..Then only i cahnged it

Comment: I am using a pulltorefresh listview in this page so i am using position-1 while updating..

Comment: can anyone help me out